JQ transformation
Suppose I have a json object like this
    {
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "1234"
}
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "6789"
}

I want it to transform it to
{
"abc": "1234",
"xyz" : "6789"
}

I have tried map and reduce. But cant wrap my head around

One way would be to reduce over all inputs, and successively build up the result object. Use the --null-input (or -n) flag for that:
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $i ({}; .[$i.name] = $i.version)' input.json

Demo
Another one would be to create a map of objects for each item, then add them all together into a result object. Use the --slurp (or -s) flag for that:
jq -s 'map({(.name): .version}) | add' input.json

Demo
Output:
{
  "abc": "1234",
  "xyz": "6789"
}

